# Retry mechanism for Web Service invocation

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am invoking web service in java. I have the requirement, tha if if there was error during web service invocation, the same Web service call needs to be retriggered after a certain predefined time interval for max attempts, say 5.

Is there any api in java I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this one http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-retryonfailure.html

It provides an annotation to specify the retry strategy.

Comment: Thanks a lot... It really saved a lot of time for me

Answer (score 4):

Spring has a retry annotation which servers the purpose

Step 1:  Add following dependency to your POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Step 2:  Enabling Spring Retry

```
To enable Spring Retry in an application, we need to add the @EnableRetry annotation to our @Configuration class:

Ex:

@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class AppConfig { ... }
```

Step 3: To add retry functionality to methods, @Retryable can be used:

```
Ex: 

@Service
public interface MyService {
    @Retryable(
      value = { SQLException.class }, 
      maxAttempts = 2,
      backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
    void retryService(String sql) throws SQLException;
    ...
}
```

Step 4.The @Recover annotation is used to define a separate recovery method when a @Retryable method fails with a specified exception:

```
Ex: 

@Service
public interface MyService {
    ...
    @Recover
    void recover(SQLException e, String sql);
}
```

See Url for more details :  http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry